# How to open 2 website urls in new tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I want to open 2 website in a new tab not in new window, but when the code runs, it opens first link but not the second one. Here is my code

```
<body onclick="doOpen()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function doOpen()
{
    window.open("http://website1.com/",'_blank');
    window.open("http://website2.com/",'_blank');
}
</script>
```

I want to open both. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The script execution stops once it loads the first website.

Comment: To the attempting editor : That was a bad edit. Please don't add the tags in the title.

Comment: It opens both for me: http://jsfiddle.net/y8eAE/  I think that the decision 'new window' or 'new tab' depends on your browser settings.

Comment: but sir, both link are open in a popup window, i want to open it in new tab

Comment: lol, most annoying website : when 1 popup isn't enough.

Comment: Tabs are a browser feature. They didn't even exist ~10 years ago, some browsers don't have them.

Answer (score -5):

you say

> `window.open("bhasoor bhasoor bhasoor");`

and expect it to open in new tab???

not sure if it exists but you should try something like

```
**tab**.open("bhasoor bhasoor bhasoor");
```

Comment: "window." refers to the browser window, not a "window". And don't "think" what an answer is, know it.